# How to change event of return key?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

i have 4 text fields , i want to parform  following actions by clicking on return key -

1- when i enter entry in one field and press return key , curser should be jumped on next

TextField .

Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `UITextField` delegate and set tag value to all your textField in series. like 1,2,3..as so on. then, make sure `scrollView` and textField tag values should not conflict.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    int nextTextFieldTag = textField.tag+1;
    UITextField *textFieldd = (UITextField*)[self.view viewWithTag:nextTextFieldTag];
    if (textFieldd!=nil) {
        if ([textField isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            [textFieldd becomeFirstResponder];
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: in additionally , i have a button for saving information after textfields, so in last that function should be executed automatically thanks

Comment: I have a few concerns with your code. 1) Not really a concern more of general wondering, what is scr? 2) What would you do if I have a `UITextField` with a tag of 2 and I have a `UIView` with a tag of 2, which one would it return for `viewWithTag`? How would you handle this sort of situation? Where is the check to make sure that it is a `UITextField`?

Comment: @Popeye scr is scrollView....

Comment: @Rajneesh071 I still have concerns about the `viewWithTag` but this would work.

Comment: @Popeye make sure scrollView and textField tag values should not conflict.

Comment: Not a fan this but I suppose it is a solution.

Comment: @Popeye you can check now... :).

Comment: Adding the check in makes it better :-) +1

Comment: where is +1 , you just removed your down vote... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Take the 4 textfields as textfield1,textfield2,textfile3,textfield4 .

In the textfield delegate method

```
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField 
{

    if([textField isEqual:textfield1]) 
    {
     [textfield2 becomeFirstResponder];
      return NO;
    }

    else if([textField isEqual:textfield2]) 
    {
     [textfield3 becomeFirstResponder];
      return NO;
    }

        // Do for other textfields
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This won't work. Because the nextTextfield will never be the current one returning ;)

Comment: so pls suggest me correct code thanks

Comment: sir what is textfield and textfield1 ??

Comment: I have edited the answer . Check this now .

Comment: Remains the same will never be the next textfield. Check my answer

Answer (score -2):

You just need to know what the next TextField should be and have `UITextFieldDelegateProtocol` especially the `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField` implemented.

In `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField` simply figure out the next TextField and do `[nextTextField becomeFirstResponder];`

---

So the `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField` Method could look like this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField 
{

    if ([textField isEqual:firstTextField]) {
        [secondTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    } 

    //When last textfield dismiss the keyboard
    else if ([textField lastTextField]) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }

    return NO;
}
```